# Netsuite Formula Field

Tags: search, field, formula, netsuite

Currently, I want to create formula fields in Netsuite which evaluates result from line items.
For example: In purchase order, sum of all line item quantities on a body field.

I am not very sure how that can be done.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a userevent script that will maintain this count in a custom field. Then this field can be accessed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. Create a custom body field in Purchase order. Example with internal id: 'custbody_sample_field_po'.
2. Create a user-event script in After Submit deployed in Purchase Order.

Here is the script:

```
var recordId = nlapiGetRecordId();
var obj = nlapiLoadRecord('purchaseorder', recordId);

//Get all line item quantity and sum it
var sum = parseInt(0);
var count = obj.getLineItemCount('item');
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    var temp = parseInt(obj.getLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i));
    sum += temp;
}

//Save the total to the custom field
obj.setFieldValue('custbody_sample_field_po', sum);
nlapiSubmitRecord(obj, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transaction body field "custbody_sum_quantity"

```
function updateTotal(type)
{
  if(type == 'create' || type == 'edit')
   {
      var id= nlapiGetRecordId();
      var type = nlapiGetRecordType();
      var record = nlapiLoadRecord(type,id);
      var count = record.getLineItemCount('item');
      var total = 0;
      if(count  > 0)
      {
       for(var i = 1; i<=count;i++)
        {
           var quantity= record.getLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', i);
           total += quantity;
         }
      }
      record.setFieldValue('custbody_sum_quantity',total );
      var recid = nlapiSubmitRecord(record,true,true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use an answer for spamming your own website; we're here to help, not advertise.